# replace the first line of file with variable using sed in python

Tags: python, bash, sed

I am trying to replace the first line of file with a variable using sed in python.
doing something like `subprocess.call(["sed -i '1s/.*/${lenN}/g' test.txt"], shell=True)`.
However, if I use single quote for `'1s/.*/${lenN}/g'`, it prints `${lenN}` in file. If I use a double quote for `'1s/.*/${lenN}/g'`, it returns SyntaxError: invalid syntax. How may I make it work?